# Rank of matrix A*B after replacing part of B with an identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider two matrices $A$ and $B$, where $A\in\mathbb{F}_q^{K\times K}$, $B\in\mathbb{F}_q^{K\times M}$, $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a finite field of size $q$, $M\leq K$. $A$ is a lower triangular matrix, i.e., $A_{ij}=0$ for $1\leq i<j\leq K$. It is known that $\text{rank}(AB)=M$. Now we replace the first $M$ rows of $B$ with an identity matrix to obtain
$$B'=\left[\begin{array}{c}I_{M\times M}\\ P\end{array}\right]$$,
where $P$ contains the last $K-M$ rows of the original B. Is that $\text{rank}(AB')$ still equal to $M$? If not, any counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $K=2$, $M=1$,
$$ A = \left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]
\qquad B = \left[\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right] $$
Then $AB = B$ but $AB' = 0$.